# How to align parent and child divs within another div in two directions?

Tags: html, css, alignment, parent-child, margins

[Model[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDO6C.png)

I am trying to get these boxes to align like the model picture using only CSS additions. I can't add margins to the cols because it separates them, and I cannot for some reason get the turquoise box aligned with its child divs, nor both sets of cols with each other.

here's a link to the code: 
[https://codepen.io/vbarczak/full/ExxdJmr][2]

```
    body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
nav {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
  height: 5px;
}

header {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#divel {
  background-color: turquoise;
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  flex-direction: column;
  order: 1;
  z-index: 4;
}
#divel div {
  margin-left: 20px;
  \: left;
  display: block;
  order: 2;
  z-index: 3;
}
.col {
  background-color: tomato;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}
#divela {
  background-color: grey;
  height: auto;
  width: 2000px;
  clear: none;
  display: inline-block;
  flex-direction: row;
  order: 2;
  margin-top: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
    }
    #divela div {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 50px;
  clear: none;
    }
    section {
  background-color: tan;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: auto;
    }
   footer {
  background-color: black;
}

<body>
  <br>
  <nav> <br></nav>
  <header><br><br><br></header>
  <section><br>
    <p><br></p>
    <div id="divel"><br>
      <div class="col"><br></div>
      <div class="col"><br></div>
      <div class="col"><br></div>
      <div class="col"><br></div>
    </div>
    <div id="divela"><br>
      <div class="col"><br></div>
      <div class="col"><br></div>
      <div class="col"><br></div>
      <div class="col"><br></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer><br></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: missing the model

Comment: fixed! @AlbertoSinigaglia